# In efficient EF generated query for odata related entity filtering request, doesn't apply Inner Join with And Clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, odata

I have 2 classes ( EF Models ) exposed as odata entityset,

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

When I query for Customers in specific city using odata filter like

> http://localhost:62680/odata/Customers?$expand=Address&$filter=Address/City eq 'Chennai'

It generates the following inefficient sql with **City filtering done in WHERE** Clause,

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    N'462b9c81-0a7a-4015-aa08-bcdb2ec067ec' AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Address_Id] AS [Address_Id], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C2], 
    N'Address' AS [C3], 
    N'462b9c81-0a7a-4015-aa08-bcdb2ec067ec' AS [C4], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C5], 
    cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
    FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Address_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[City] = @p__linq__0)
```

Ideally, it should have generated query with **And clause in Inner join** for filtering the city like the one below

```
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        N'462b9c81-0a7a-4015-aa08-bcdb2ec067ec' AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[Address_Id] AS [Address_Id], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C2], 
        N'Address' AS [C3], 
        N'462b9c81-0a7a-4015-aa08-bcdb2ec067ec' AS [C4], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[State] AS [State], 
        [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C5], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
        FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Address_Id] = [Extent2].[Id] 
and ([Extent2].[City] = @p__linq__0)
```

Is there any way I can influence the query generation process for Odata request. Please advise.

**Library Info :**

Microsoft.AspNet.OData : 7.0.1
Entity Framework : 6.2

Comment: I know this is years old, but I'm pretty sure you need to put your filter in the expand. Something like `$expand=Address($filter=Address/City eq 'Chennai')`